# Parsing a date in Korean

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a date in Korean Date format using SimpleDateFormat which works. However i would like to remove any dependency on adding up Korean Characters in Pattern for Year(년), Month(월) and Day(일) and so on.

```
    String dateinKorean = "2013년 9월 26일 (목)";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'년' M'월' d'일' '('EE')'",  Locale.KOREA);
    try {
        Date dt = sdf.parse(dateinKorean);
        System.out.println(dt.toGMTString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am trying to use DateFormatSymbols Class to Parse the date using the Locale, however the problem is I am not able to parse the complete date, I can parse an individual Month(MM), Year(yyyy) or Day(dd) without any issues.

```
        DateFormatSymbols df = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.KOREAN);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd", df);
        try {
            // 2013년 9월 26일
            Date dt = sdf.parse("2013년 9월 26일");
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
```

Can anyone please help me identify if there is any other way to parse the dates other than shown above ?

Answer (score 0):

If the date format includes "fixed" characters they are used as-is, so if you include words like "year" or "month" in the format they cannot be ignored.

You can hack your way around this by removing all non-digits from the string before parsing, for example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", df);
    Date dt = sdf.parse("2013년 9월 26일".replaceAll("\\D+", "-"));
```

A better solution could be [internationalizing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html) the date format so that each language you support could have a format of its own.